# Google Apps Script fails to implement concurrency

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, concurrency

### Problem Statement

I am trying to scrub DNC (do not call) phone records from a skip-traced spreadsheet that is almost 1000 rows long, and each row can have up to 10 phone records.

Each phone record consists of the following data:

- DNC status ('Yes' or 'No')
- Score (how accurate was the skip trace for that record)
- Type (Land line/Mobile/...)
- Phone number
- Last seen date

### How I chose to come at the problem

I create this class `DNCScrubber`, which does the following:

- extracts the data from the target `Sheet` into an array of dictionaries that all contain some `phoneDataList`
- cleans up the data, namely the `phoneDataList`s and use the data to set some `rowsToDelete`, and then
- updates the sheet, overwriting the phone records only if they don't match the `phoneDataList`, and blanking out anything past that

The latter first breaks the sheet into 100-row chunks, and then asynchronously operates on each chunk, like this :

```
  updateSheet(sheet) { 
    let breakpoints = [];
    for (let breakpoint = 0; breakpoint < this.sheetData.length; breakpoint += Constants.SheetChunkSize) { 
      breakpoints.push([breakpoint, Math.min(breakpoint + Constants.SheetChunkSize, this.sheetData.length)])
    }

    const updateSheetPromises = breakpoints.map(([startIdx, endIdx]) => this.updateSheetChunkAsync(sheet, startIdx, endIdx))

    Promise.all(updateSheetPromises)
      .then((_) => { 
        // delete the rows to be deleted
        this.rowsToDelete.reverse()
          .forEach((rowIdx) => { 
            Logger.log(`Deleting row ${rowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart} ... `)
            sheet.deleteRow(rowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart);
            Logger.log(`Row ${rowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart} deleted!`)
          })

        // write the data to another sheet

      })


  }

  updateSheetChunkAsync(sheet, startIdx, endIdx) { 
    const firstPhoneDNCIdx = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
      .getValues()[0]
      .indexOf(Constants.FirstPhoneDNCColumn);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sheetData
        .slice(startIdx, endIdx)
        .forEach((rowData, rowIdx) => { 
          const currentRowIdx = rowIdx + startIdx,
            currentRowNumber = currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart;

          Logger.log(`Scrubbing DNC records from row ${currentRowNumber} ...`);
          if (this.rowsToDelete.includes(currentRowIdx))
            return;

          rowData[Constants.PhoneDataList].forEach((phoneNumberData, idx) => { 
            let dncCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, 
                firstPhoneDNCIdx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart + (idx * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount)),
              scoreCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, 
                firstPhoneDNCIdx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart + (idx * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount) + 1),
              typeCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, 
                firstPhoneDNCIdx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart + (idx * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount) + 2),
              phoneNumberCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, 
                firstPhoneDNCIdx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart + (idx * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount) + 3),
              lastSeenCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, 
                firstPhoneDNCIdx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart + (idx * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount) + 4);

            if (dncCell.getValue() === 'YES')
              dncCell.setValue(phoneNumberData.isDNC);
            if (phoneNumberCell.getValue() != phoneNumberData.phoneNumber) { 
              scoreCell.setValue(phoneNumberData.score);
              typeCell.setValue(phoneNumberData.phoneType);
              lastSeenCell.setValue(phoneNumberData.lastSeenDate);
            }
          })

          const firstCellIdxToBlankOut = firstPhoneDNCIdx + (rowData[Constants.PhoneDataList].length * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount);
          for (let idx = firstCellIdxToBlankOut;
            idx < firstPhoneDNCIdx + (10 * Constants.PhoneDataColumnCount) - 1;
            idx++) { 
            
            let blankCell = sheet.getRange(currentRowIdx + Constants.FirstDataRowRangeStart, idx + Constants.ColumnRangeStart);
            if (blankCell.getValue() != '')
              blankCell.clearContent();
          }

          Logger.log(`Row ${currentRowNumber} scrubbed of DNC records!`);
        })

        resolve(true);
    })
  }
```

### Problem with that attempt

The first 200 rows seem to zip by...

However, right around row 201, things start...slowing...down...

I start seeing the processing of each row take anywhere from 2 seconds to 5 seconds..and this is regardless of that those rows were already cleared of DNC records!

Even worse:

> Function execution has timed out. Restart the debugger to continue debugging.Restart debugger

What can I do to leverage concurrency here, to defeat that timeout issue/bottleneck?!

### Ridiculously simplified example

Here is a [ridiculously simplified example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LzBsWpU8dSBttAasUVNorVhcZB7Wj7NtMMdOedxKM6g/edit?usp=sharing) that only contains 10 rows of data, 3 phone records per row, with raw data Sheet and expected output Sheet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First, in the current stage, Google Apps Script is run a synchronous process. So, if your script is run as Google Apps Script, from `The latter first breaks the sheet into 100-row chunks, and then asynchronously operates on each chunk, like this :`, I guessed that you might have wanted to reduce the process cost of the script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, how about creating a script with a low process cost?

Comment: But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `I am trying to scrub DNC (do not call) phone records from a spreadsheet that is almost 1000 rows long, and each row can have up to 10 phone records.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do, and it seems like my code is as optimal as it can get for the task at hand...

The task is as follows: 

for each row of the spreadsheet (roughly 1000 rows of data)
  remove the records of that row where DNC = 'Yes'
  move the next non-DNC (DNC = 'No') record into that place

I can't imagine a more efficient way to do so than to do what I have outlined above. 

I have updated the approach description as it was not consistent with my actual code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `The task is as follows: for each row of the spreadsheet (roughly 1000 rows of data) remove the records of that row where DNC = 'Yes' move the next non-DNC (DNC = 'No') record into that place I can't imagine a more efficient way to do so than to do what I have outlined above.` and updated question, I cannot still understand what you want to do.

Comment: But, I would like to support you. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @MikeWarren Please share a minimal reproducible sample of your sheet, so the community will have better chance of understanding your issue and can help you have a solution for your project once they have the chance to play around your data and replicate what is hapening.

Comment: Here is a [ridiculously simplified example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LzBsWpU8dSBttAasUVNorVhcZB7Wj7NtMMdOedxKM6g/edit?usp=sharing) that only contains 10 rows of data, 3 phone records per row, with raw data Sheet and expected output Sheet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MikeWarren I do apologize for this I understand that it is important to keep the data safe, however can you make your example more distinguishable, with the same phone number on your sample it is really hard to find different scenarios, I understand that you can have code that basically shows what you want, code can be misleading in pushing it through the most efficient way to go through your data. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You're calling `setValue` inside a for loop, is it possible for you to make changes in memory and then do one final `setValues` once you've finished processing the data?

Answer (score 0):

### Processing Scrubbing Faster

I can see that the main reasons why you are not processing data inefficiently is because of the constant call per instance on each sheet which greatly impacts your runtime. I have created a code that will suffice your baser needs with a little bit of tweaks you can easily integrate on your project.

The original code has been overly created. So based on your provided sample sheet, you just need to detect "YES" and "NO" on the data. I have provided a code that you can use as a reference for your project.

### Sample Code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

/* I haven't included your chunking and promises part of your code as those are not really inefficient I only refactor the part where you have to do it per cell
 The next Block of code will get data from your Source Sheets and then process it to remove the "YES" values if there is a "NO" in the DNC Col of the ROWS. */
function getDatafromSheets(){
var newData = []

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw data");
var originalRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var  orginalData = originalRange.getValues();
orginalData.forEach(row => {
  if(row.some(elem => elem === "NO")){
    var updatedDatum = row.map(item => (item === "YES") ? "" : item)
    newData.push(updatedDatum)
 }

})
// Instead of clearing and rewriting everything each instance of your loop since we got the updated data. I really suggest going it over only once instead of per cell hence will greatly improve your runtime
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Result Sheet") // You can change it to wherever you want, it is simply removing everything within one go.
var clearRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn);
clearRange.clearContent();
// Then you will paste the processed data
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1, newData.length, newData[0].length); // Please set the "newData[0].length" to value of your longest row or longest Data being process as I do not have clear information of your Data
targetRange.setValues(newData);
}
```

The blocks of code are working perfectly with your current sample data.

### References:

[Clear Contents:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

[MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[SOME](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If you have any questions or you want to clarify about this answer please feel free to comment.